# How to return 0 if a pattern is matched from a file?

Tags: android, shell, grep, kernel, output

I have a binary that repacks android kernel (not mkbootimg).
I'm making a script to automate the process.

**I don't want any output on the screen. So I have redirected the output to a file named foo.log.**

My current working folder is `data/local/working/`.
The command is - `kernel_make "$zImage" "$ramdisk" "$cmdline" "$image" &> data/local/working/foo.log`

What I've to do is, if the last line of the output (foo.log) is this -

`"targed file $1 is patched sucesfully, enjoy new kernel"`

Then return 0 and exit. Else return 1 and exit.

I'm trying to do with grep, but as I'm new to command line, do don't have any idea of doing it the right way.

Please be free to ask if anything more is required..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a common usage for that would be `grep -q 'pattern'`, it doesn't generate any output, but you can check the return value of the command to decide if the pattern was found. See this example:

```
kent$ echo "foo"|grep -q bar
kent$ echo $?               
1
kent$ echo "bar"|grep -q bar
kent$ echo $?               
0
```

hope this is what you are looking for.

To extract the last line, you can use `tail` command.

In fact, you can also do it with `awk` in one shot:

```
..cmd with..output|awk 'END{if (!/pattern/)exit 1}'
```

then you can check the `$?`

Comment: Thanks! I was trying it. But then I discovered something.
Please see the question again, I've modified it a bit. :)

Comment: @ChinmayKunkikar read the file then. change my `tail -1 file|grep ...` with the awk one: `awk 'END{.....' file`

Comment: `lastline=$(tail -n1 logfile) if grep pattern <<<"$lastline" &>/dev/null; then echo "yay, found pattern" else echo "darn" fi`  This worked too. Thanks anyways.